# asp.net hiddenfield.value is not updated by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hidden-field

I want to assign a value to an asp.net hiddenfield via javascript prior to post back.

But in the code behind  the hidden fieldvalue is null. The code I am using is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True" Visible="True">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger   ControlID="save1"    EventName="Click">         
            </asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
       </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>

 <asp:Button ID="save1" runat="server" Text="Send"  OnClientClick="return SaveFase();"  />

       function SaveFase() {     
           var UP = jQuery.get('<% = HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
           UP.Value= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          return true             
       }

Protected Sub PassBackImage(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save1.Click

      dim Value = HiddenField1.Value      
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to write:

```
$('#<% = HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

Also, put your javascript function in a sctipt block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function SaveFase() {     
           return $('#<% = HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
       }
<script>
```

Comment: this works great
$('#<% = HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

thanks guys

Comment: @Marky68 no worries, consider upvoting the answers which have helped you and accepting the answer which best/first answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
var UP = jQuery('#<% = HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
UP.val("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery.get (which is a call to an HTTP GET method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), use

```
jQuery.find('#' + <% = HiddenField1.ClientID %>)
```

Then from there it should work.  If it doesn't, use an error console to see what errors are being raised when the call is made (most browsers have one built in.